# Does setPageable() of PrinterJob class accepts PdfDecoder object

Tags: pdf, javafx-2, jpedal

I am trying to print the pdf file using javafx,jpedal library.I followed the below link for reference.

http://www.wisecodes.com/2009/08/print-pdf-with-jpedal/

If i use this link i am getting the error in this line

```
pjPrintJob.setPageable(pdfD);
```

It is telling that setPageable method of PrinterJob does not accept the PdfDecoder object.

I have searched in google regarding this.But i found that so many are using like this.How is it possible.Can any one help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using the LGPL version, which unfortunately doesn't have support for printing.